# Как запустить QTimer в QtConcurrent::run

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qt5

Kак запустить запустить `QTimer` в `QtConcurrent::run`?

Я попробовал так, но пишет - не правильный вызов функции:

```
for (int i =0; i < test_checkbox.length(); i++ )
{
    if (Value == true)
    {
        if(test_checkbox[i]->isChecked() ==Value)
        {
               // timer->start(struc_mess_add.MS);  // так работает
               QtConcurrent::run(timer->start(vector_struc_mess_add[i].MS),&timer); // запустит слот после окончания временного промежутка  
               // создаю поток с своим таймером
         }
    } else {
        qDebug() << "chekbocks:" << " False";
        timer->stop(); // обязательно надо завершить timer, ведет себя(timer) считай как поток !.
    }
}
```

А вот слот на который он завязан:

```
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(KAN_minimal())); // делаю соединение
```

В заголовочном файле:

```
QTimer *timer  = new QTimer(); // !!! создаю таймер
```

---

Пытался через вектор попробывать. Но при этом не выдаёт ошибку.

```
 timer = new QTimer();      // объявляем и инициализируем timer
 vector_qtimer.append(timer);   // кладём timer  в вектор

 vector_qtimer[i]->start(vector_struc_mess_add[i].MS);
```

В заголовочном файле:

```
 QTimer *timer  = new QTimer(); // !!! создаю таймер  
 QVector<QTimer*> vector_qtimer;
```

Comment: Что хотите этим кодом ```QtConcurrent::run(timer->start(vector_struc_mess_add[i].MS),&timer);``` сделать? Зачем здесь ```QtConcurrent::run(...)```?

Comment: @tequillaz я пытаюсь создать множество, таймеров чтобы запустить действия, на каждое действие новый таймер со своим счётчиком времени.

Comment: @tequillaz `timer->start(vector_struc_mess_add[i].MS);` вот так одно действие со своим временем работает, но мне надо запустить множество таких действий у каждого из которых будет своё время.

Comment: Так и запускайте без ```QtConcurrent::run(...)```, зачем же он тут привязан?

Comment: @tequillaz  да я попробовал вектором `vector_qtimer[i]->start(vector_struc_mess_add[i].MS);` но он код не выполняет и это при том что все прекрасно собирается

Answer (score 1):

`QtConcurrent::run(...)` лишний, сигналы/слоты прекрасно отрабатывают без него. При динамическом создании таймеров и размещением их в вектор Вы забываете сигналы вновь созданного таймера соединить со слотом.

Comment: НО как запустить  несколько  действий ???????? К примеру запускаю не одну а две отправки сообщения  с определённой чистотой времени. КАК Это сделать КОГДА qtimer "зажимает"  поток

Comment: Делайте неблокирующий вызов в том месте программы, где непосредственно выполняется отправка сообщения. Вот именно там ```QtConcurrent::run(...)``` поможет